# Performance difference between storing the asset as subdocument vs single document in Mongoose

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

I have an API for synchronizing contacts from the user's phone to our database. The controller essentially iterates the data sent in the request body and if it passes validation a new contact is saved:

```
const contact = new Contact({ phoneNumber, name, surname, owner });
await contact.save();
```

Having a DB with 100 IOPS and considering the average user has around 300 contacts, when the server is busy this API takes a lot of time.

Since the frontend client is made in a way that a contact ID is necessary for other operations (edit, delete), I was thinking about changing the data structure to subdocuments, and instead of saving each Contact as a separate document, the idea is to save one document with many contacts inside:

```
const userContacts = new mongoose.Schema({
   owner: //the id of the contacts owner,
   contacts: [new mongoose.Schema({
     name: { type: String },
     phone: { type: String }
   })]
});
```

This way I have to do just one save. But since Mongo has to generate an ID for each subdocument, is this really that much faster than the original approach?

Comment: The IDs are generated on the client.

Comment: @AlexBlex so this means that this approach will be way faster right? do you see any problems of going  from single doc to subdoc?

Comment: Yep, it will be faster. Problems - no, apart from you will need to change everything that works with contacts. It will be a bit more complex to CRUD individual contacts stored as subdocs in useContacts collection vs individual documents stored in contacts collection.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Summary

This really depends on your exact usage scenarios:

- are contacts often updated?
- what is the max / average quantity of contacts per user
- are they ever partially loaded, or are they always fetched all together?

But for a fairly common collection such as contacts, I would not recommend storing them in subdocuments.

Instead you should be able to use [`insertMany`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26029099/fragmentation-in-mongodb-when-growing-documents) for your initial sync scenario.

### Explanation

Storing as subdocuments makes a bulk-write easier will make querying and updating contacts slower and more awkward than as regular documents.

For example, if I have 100 contacts, and I want to view and edit 1 of them, it needs to load the full 100 contacts. I can make the change via a partial update using `$set` or `$update`, so the update will be OK. But when I add a new contact, I will have to add a new contact subDocument to you Contacts document. This makes it a growing document, meaning your database will suffer from fragmentation which can slow things down a lot (see this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26029099/fragmentation-in-mongodb-when-growing-documents))

You will have to use aggregate with [$ projection](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/projection/positional/) or [$unwind](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/unwind/) to search through contacts in MongoDB. If you want to apply a specific sort order, this too would have to be done via aggregate or in code.

Matching via projection can also lead to problems with duplicate contacts being difficult to find.

And this won't scale. What if you get users with 1000s of contacts later? Then this single document will grow large and querying it will become very slow.

#### Alternatives

If your contacts for sync are in the 100s, you might get away with a splitting them into groups of ~50-100 and calling [`insertMany`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26029099/fragmentation-in-mongodb-when-growing-documents) for each batch.

If they grow into the thousands, then I would suggest uploading all contacts, saving them as JSON / CSV files  to disk, then slowly processing these in the background in batches.

Comment: You can use projection/aggregation to load individual contacts from the array. Not sure how nicely it will play with Mongoose tho. Subdocuments are perfectly searchable and you can have them indexed https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/index-multikey/  I agree with the general idea tho - it will require more efforts to work with individual contacts.

Comment: @AlexBlex thank you for the link, I forgot about multikey indexes on subdocuments - I can't remember the last time I needed them. I'll update the answer with your points & links